# What are the differences between clang under different paths?

Tags: c, macos, unix, clang

I'm currently under `OS X 10.10.4`.

When I ran `sudo find / -name "clang" -print` I got the output

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.8/src/platform-native/org/gradle/nativeplatform/toolchain/internal/clang
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/lib/clang
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/clang
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang
Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/swift/clang
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang
/Users/yangyy/.vim/bundle/clang_complete/plugin/clang
/Users/yangyy/.vim/bundle/YCM-Generator/fake-toolchain/Unix/clang
/Users/yangyy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/tests/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/tools/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/tools/clang/bindings/python/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/tools/clang/include/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/tools/clang/test/Driver/Inputs/mips_mti_linux/lib/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra/test/clang-tidy/Inputs/Headers/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/bin/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/lib/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/lib/cmake/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/tools/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/tools/clang/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/tools/clang/include/clang
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/tools/clang/lib/cmake/clang
/usr/bin/clang
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang
```

Then I did `which clang` and got

```
/usr/bin/clang
```

To examine whether they are identical, I checked the version of the one in `Xcode` and the default one and I found that they are exactly the same version

```
/usr/bin/clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

- **What are the differences between those `clang`s? (I doubt they are actually identical.) Should I remove all of them except the default one?**

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT

I've found something might be helpful from [Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6042251?tstart=0). It seems someone ran into the same situation with mine, but I'm not quite understand the reason they discussed and the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know if some `clang` are symbolic links to other, you can try the following command:

```
find / -name clang +exec file {} + 2> /dev/null
```